# how to scp multiple files from multiple directories, while different files in different directories may have the same name

Tags: linux, scp

I want to scp several files from remote to local, the files in remote is like this:
    /data/1792348/a.stat
    /data/1792348/b.stat
    /data/187657/a.stat
    /data/187657/b.stat
    ... ...

1792348 187657 etc, the middle directory name is random.

how can i scp all the files ends with *.stat* from remote to local?
if i tried *scp -P36000 user@host:/data/*/*.stat .*, i can only get 2 files *a.stat b.stat*.

why i can's submit this question?
i really don't know how to solve this, and hadn't search a answer from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use `rsync` (which uses scp internally; but is way more elaborate, e.g. it will only transmit minimal changesets of data, so if you run it several times, you will get an impressive speedup)

```
rsync -avz /data/ \
   --include "*/" --include "*.stat" --exclude "*" \
   user@host:/path/to/dest/data/
```

Comment: finally i remote ssh to tar the files, then use rsync. thanks!

Comment: if you are using `tar`, then you don't need `rsync` at all; simply do `tar cf user@host:/path/to/dest/data.tgz /data/*/*.stat` on the remote machine...